How to auto-run a deployed executable Blazor WASM interactive server app on window start up?
I have developed and deployed my ASP.NET Core app on a local machine for offline operations and generated an executable file for the app. So, I used Blazor WASM interactive server with .NET 8.0, I'm not sure what is the optimal way to auto run the .exe file on window startup? When I run the .exe file, the deployed app will be opened on a default browser on the machine. Thank you all
I would like to see an efficient way of doing this beside attaching the .exe file on the startup tab on task manager on window. I have heard about using window service on visual studio but not sure how it works? Does the script on window service execute the Blazor .exe file or something?

1. Add Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices Package.
2. Change your Program.cs file like below.
using BlazorApp1.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

// Add this line
builder.Services.AddWindowsService();
// Add this line
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(5100); // http port
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();

3. Publish the project and navigate to the folder, then run the command to create the windows service. Here is my sample command.
sc.exe create ".NET Joke Service20210829" binpath= "C:\Users\Jason\source\repos\BlazorApp-empty1\BlazorApp1\bin\Release\net8.0\publish\BlazorApp1.exe"



